# Exercise: Web Crawler - concurrency not working

Tags: concurrency, go

I am going through the golang tour and working on the final exercise to change a web crawler to crawl in parallel and not repeat a crawl ( http://tour.golang.org/#73 ). All I have changed is the crawl function.

```
    var used = make(map[string]bool)

    func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher) {
        if depth <= 0 {
            return
        }
        body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
        if err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
            return
        }
        fmt.Printf("\nfound: %s %q\n\n", url, body)
        for _,u := range urls {
            if used[u] == false {
                used[u] = true
                Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher)
            }
        }
        return
    }
```

In order to make it concurrent I added the go command in front of the call to the function Crawl, but instead of recursively calling the Crawl function the program only finds the "http://golang.org/" page and no other pages.

Why doesn't the program work when I add the go command to the call of the function Crawl?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem seems to be, that your process is exiting before all URLs can be followed
by the crawler. Because of the concurrency, the `main()` procedure is exiting before
the workers are finished.

To circumvent this, you could use [`sync.WaitGroup`](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup):

```
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer wg.Done()
    if depth <= 0 {
         return
    }
    body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nfound: %s %q\n\n", url, body)
    for _,u := range urls {
        if used[u] == false {
           used[u] = true
           wg.Add(1)
           go Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, wg)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

And call `Crawl` in `main` as follows:

```
func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}

    Crawl("http://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, wg)

    wg.Wait()
}
```

Also, [don't rely on the map being thread safe](http://golang.org/doc/go_faq.html#atomic_maps).

Comment: Where was the used map declared? I'm assuming it's a map[string]bool type. In this case you're 'sharing' memory to communicate though, instead of communicating to share memory since I believe your code relies on used being shared by all the Crawl calls.

Comment: AFAIR I used the code from the question and didn't change it except for the addition of the `WaitGroup`, simply to show how it is used. You're right that in the example the map is assumed to be thread-safe which it is not and I explicitly warned not to rely on this. But I agree that this might not be read like that and I also didn't give a counterexample.

Comment: Thanks for the additional helpful comment nemo. That clears things up for me.

Comment: Afaik there's a race condition with your solution. Some urls that are in depth two may not get fetched. If there's an url nested too deep, but also at depth 1, and the gouroutines fetch first the one nested too deep, then it wont get crawled as it's current depth.

Comment: yes, there is a race condition. I explained in my previous comment and I said so in my answer. I merely adoptef OPs code to show how to use waitgroups

Comment: note that you should call 'wg.Done()' before every return otherwise you will wait indefinitely in case of error / depth condition. It's achieved by calling 'defer wg.Done()' at the start of Crawl

Comment: I get a `panic: sync: negative WaitGroup counter`, which is fixed by adding `wg.Add(1)` to the `main()` function prior to calling `Crawl` too.

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach, again using [sync.WaitGroup](http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) but wrapping the fetch function in a anonymous goroutine. To make the url map thread safe (meaning parallel threads can't access and change values at the same time) one should wrap the url map in a new type with a [sync.Mutex](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#Mutex) type included i.e. the `fetchedUrls` type in my example and use the `Lock` and `Unlock` methods while the map is being searched/updated.

```
type fetchedUrls struct {
    urls map[string]bool
    mux sync.Mutex
}

// Crawl uses fetcher to recursively crawl
// pages starting with url, to a maximum of depth.
func Crawl(url string, depth int, fetcher Fetcher, used fetchedUrls, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    if depth <= 0 {
        return
    }
    used.mux.Lock()
    if used.urls[url] == false {
        used.urls[url] = true
        wg.Add(1)
        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            body, urls, err := fetcher.Fetch(url)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println(err)
                return
            }
            fmt.Printf("found: %s %q\n", url, body)
            for _, u := range urls {
                Crawl(u, depth-1, fetcher, used, wg)
            }
            return
        }()
    }
    used.mux.Unlock()
    return
}

func main() {
    wg := &sync.WaitGroup{}
    used := fetchedUrls{urls: make(map[string]bool)}
    Crawl("https://golang.org/", 4, fetcher, used, wg)
    wg.Wait()
}
```

Output:

```
found: https://golang.org/ "The Go Programming Language"
not found: https://golang.org/cmd/
found: https://golang.org/pkg/ "Packages"
found: https://golang.org/pkg/os/ "Package os"
found: https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/ "Package fmt"

Program exited.
```

Comment: the problem with this solution if you lock it like this: there is no parallelism.
You are essentially running it one Crawl at a time.

Answer (score 0):

I created my 2 implementations(different concurrency designs) of the same [here](https://github.com/deepanshululla/golang-mini-projects/blob/master/multithreaded_web_crawler/main.go).

it also uses a thread-safe map

[playground link](https://goplay.tools/snippet/KYBCMAdvriy)