# How to use a dedicated channel to signal the end of a crawl job in go

Tags: concurrency, go, web-crawler, channel

This is a follow up from [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29491795/webcrawler-in-go).

I am trying to build a prototype for a webcrawler and I want to use a `chan` to block the execution until all the jobs are done, just as in

```
func main() {
    go func() {
        do_stuff()
        stop <- true
   }
    fmt.Println(<-stop)
}
```

There is a `queue` function that dispatch the jobs to the workers. When all jobs are finished, the function will also the channel and send a signal.

```
type Job int

//simulating a worker that processes a html page and returns some more links
func worker(in chan Job, out chan Job, num int) {
    for element := range in {
        if element%2 == 0 {
            out <- 100*element + 5
            out <- 100*element + 3
            out <- 100*element + 1
        }
    }
}

func queue(toWorkers chan<- Job, fromWorkers <-chan Job, init Job, stop chan bool) {
    var list []Job
    var currentJobs int
    currentJobs = 0
    list = append(list, init)
    done := make(map[Job]bool)
    for {
        var send chan<- Job
        var item Job
        if len(list) > 0 {
            send = toWorkers
            item = list[0]
        } else if currentJobs == 0 {
            close(toWorkers)
            // this messes up everything!
            stop <- true
            return
        }

        select {
        case send <- item:
            currentJobs += 1
            // We sent an item, remove it
            list = list[1:]
        case thing := <-fromWorkers:
            currentJobs -= 1
            // Got a new thing
            if !done[thing] {
                list = append(list, thing)
                done[thing] = true
            }
        }
    }

}

func main() {
    in := make(chan Job, 1)
    out := make(chan Job, 1)
    stop := make(chan bool)
    // dispatches jobs to workers
    go queue(in, out, 0, stop)
    for i := 0; i < max_workers; i++ {
        go worker(in, out, i)
    }
    duration := time.Second
    time.Sleep(duration)
    // this cause deadlock
    fmt.Println(<-stop)
}
```

[Link to playground](https://play.golang.org/p/AKWV31TCZi)

If I understand correctly, the problem is with the `stop` channel: when the workers still have jobs, go thinks that no one will send to that channel and declares deadlock. The function `queue` will both close the `toWorkers` channel and send a signal to `stop`, but not while there are outstanding jobs. 
What am I missing?

Comment: Removed my comments - I would say refactor it for waitgroups as explained in the answer below - for now.

Comment: The problem is that you can't decrement `currentJobs` anytime you receive from a worker! My answer on the linked question mentions ways to do it correctly (via a separate "I've finished a request" channel, or via a *special* value on the `fromWorkers` channel where the suggestions).

Comment: BTW, as mentioned elsewhere here, and on my previous answer, a wait group could be used as well. But in this case it's effectively just doing simple counting and *if* you can easily/trivially get the relevant information to a single place (the `queue` function) it can just count itself without the overhead of a wait group. Wait groups are useful when you need to make the `Add`, `Done`, and `Wait` calls from two or three different goroutines.

Comment: Thanks @DaveC, I see the problem now. So you are saying I should use a `chan` to receive the signal from a routine that the Job is done (regardless of the fact that more stuff is sent to `queue`)? Should that be an array of `chan` (one for each worker)?

Comment: At this point you should be able to identify a solution that fits your specific use case and that you understand well. Possibly that means having the web page fetcher examine the page and [assemble all the "child" links and send them out as a single slice](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/9) so you only have a single channel send from each worker; then you *could* use that as a signal the worker is done. Possibly you could wait groups, possibly you could use something else.

Comment: E.g. [here is an example full solution](https://gist.github.com/dchapes/1cfb9f304c607e9b185e) to the previously linked [Go Tour excercise](https://tour.golang.org/concurrency/9).

Answer (score 4):

Use sync.WaitGroup to wait for all the go routines to end.

http://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup

http://blog.golang.org/pipelines

I made a small example here: http://play.golang.org/p/P30LdV0Gfe

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sync"
)

func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    routinesNo := 10
    wg.Add(routinesNo)
    for i := 0; i < routinesNo; i++ {
        go func(n int) {
            fmt.Printf("%d ", n)
            wg.Done()
        }(i)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("\nThe end!")
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this was my first approach. But I still want to use a `chan` to wait for the code to finish

Comment: @meto, you still need to refactor anyway. Checking for `currentJobs == 0` is a race, since that condition could be true at anytime during processing.

Comment: @JimB, it's not a race, that variable is only visible and referenced as a local variable. If you refer to my answer on the linked question I mentioned ways of correctly decrementing that are not used in this question. (The idea was to avoid overhead of a wait group).

Comment: @DaveC, sorry, "race" may not have been a good word. It's a logic problem, a race in a sense, between the sends and receives. There's no guarantee you'll get >=1 send for every receive in the select (concurrently actionable select cases are taken at random)

Comment: When done right (not as in this question) it's not a "logic problem" and is perfectly fine and just as good as a wait group or any other solution. It's basically taking a wait group that happens to have the `Add` and `Done` calls only ever done within a single instance of a single function and turing them into `counter++` and `counter--` instead.