# Golang: to goroutine or not to goroutine?

Tags: multithreading, http, go, goroutine

Many times when developing an http server in Go I have this dilemma.

Assuming I want to respond to the client with `http statuscode 200` as fast as possible (and then perform work at the back), this is why I usually do:

I have my main http handler receive the request, I write `http 200` to the response, and I send a message over a `channel` (if I have `N` workers listening on that `channel`, I am using a `buffered channel` of `N`):

```
func myHttpHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    rw.WriteHeader(200)
    log(req)
}

func log(req *http.Request) {
    msg := createLog(req)
    if msg != nil {
        channel <- msg
    }
}
```

I have my listeners (fired off on init) listening forever on that channel:

```
func init() {
    for i := 0; i < workerCount; i++ {
        go worker(i, maxEntrySize, maxBufferSize, maxBufferTime)
    }
}

func worker(workerID int, maxEntrySize int, maxBufferSize int, maxBufferTime time.Duration) {
    for {
        entry := <-channel
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

Now, my main question is: should I fire off the `log(req)` function inside a go routine? i.e.

```
func myHttpHandler(rw http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    rw.WriteHeader(200)
    go func() { log(req) } ()
}
```

As far as I can gather, there's no point in opening up a goroutine for every http request in this case.

Since the current operation of the `log(req)` function is mostly sending some data over a `channel` - that operation is super quick. The only time when it's not quick - is if the `channel` blocks. Now, if the `channel` blocks, it has to mean that the worker is blocked. And since the worker listens for messages on the channel forever - if the worker is blocked, it means my machine is truly not capable to produce faster output (the worker does some `I/O` as you can imagine, but that's also very quick, because the I/O only happens once per minute).

Furthermore, since I have `N` workers, the `channel` I am using to send the messages on from the handler is buffered with `N`, so it only blocks if all `N` workers are blocked.

Is this correct? What are the pros and cons of using a `goroutine` for the `log(req)` call? This handler receives upto 10K requests per second, I am guessing it's not a good idea to open a `goroutine` for each request.

Comment: the http.Request is only valid for the duration of that request. Once your handler exits, the state of the Request is unknown, and the its connection could even be serving another request.

Comment: Doing the `log()` call in a goroutine so that the handler can return quickly if the channel would block is just using goroutines as an expensive buffering mechanism. If you want to return quickly when your workers are busy and just queue the work for later then use a queue. You can make a simple concurrent safe queue with one extra goroutine that `log()` sends to. That goroutine would append input from that channel onto a slice and write the first element (if any) to your worker channel ([e.g. like this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29498219/55504)).

Answer (score 5):

> There's no point in opening up a goroutine for every http request in this case.

That already happens when you use `net/http`'s Server. Your handler is invoked in a goroutine of its own.

> I am guessing it's not a good idea to open a goroutine for each request.

It's not a bad idea either. Go's runtime can easily handle hundreds of thousands of goroutines.

However, if `log` blocks, you risk timing out on your client, who is waiting to receive a full HTTP response and only doing `rw.WriteHeader(200)` doesn't constitute one yet.

To remedy this, you can do something like:

```
if cr, ok := rw.(io.Closer) {
    cr.Close()
}
```

And it's also probably a good idea to set the `Content-Length` header of your response to `0`.

Comment: Thanks. I know go does that (fire up the handler func inside a go routine), but it's not really relevant to my question (the question is about firing up another go routine to prevent blocking). Thanks for the bit of information about closing with io.Closer. re: the content-length, I'm actually returning some content (1x1 pixel) but thanks (wanted to spare outside the point detail from my question)